# how can i catch exception occurred in putty using .net

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

**how can i catch exception occurred in putty using .net**

what I am doing is sending some shell scripts file to putty using .net code now i  want to catch any error occured in the script file and handle it using my .net code. Any idea how this can be done

```
`try
        {
            StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //outputBuilder = null;
            string CommandSetFileName = "D://POC.txt";
            Process objProcess = new Process();
            //objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "putty.exe";
            //objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "@" + txtIP.Text.Trim() + " -pw " + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + " -m " + CommandSetFileName;

            ProcessStartInfo objInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            objInfo.FileName = "putty.exe";
            objInfo.Arguments = txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "@" + txtIP.Text.Trim() + " -pw " + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + " -m " + CommandSetFileName;
            objInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            objInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            objInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            objInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            objProcess.StartInfo = objInfo;

            objProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            // attach the event handler for OutputDataReceived before starting the process 
            objProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {         // append the new data to the data already read-in         
                    outputBuilder.Append(e.Data);
                }
                    );

            objProcess.Start();

            objProcess.BeginOutputReadLine(); 
            objProcess.WaitForExit(); 
            objProcess.CancelOutputRead();  // use the output 
            string output = outputBuilder.ToString(); 



            //string output = objProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            objProcess.WaitForExit();

            string error = objProcess.StandardError.ReadLine();

            objProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect UNIX", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }`
```

this is the code i am using

Comment: Do you mean an error when the script is executed or when the script is moved?

Comment: I want to catch the eroors when when the script is executed

Comment: @SLaks  i have posted the code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch any errors that may occur when **sending/copying** you could try the following: (I'm not too familar with putty)

```
try
{
  //Send scripts
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //Handle error
}
finally
{
  //Cleanup resources if necessary
}
```

**Note: It's recommended to catch the specific exception types as opposed to `Exception`, the above code is just an example.**

If you want to handle errors that occur during a scripts **execution** then the above code may not be helpful.

Could you provide any further information?